# Counting sort in C

Tags: c, sorting, counting

I have a problem with Counting sort. When i will sort table sometimes it work but sometimes no (It doesn't work when k == size) and i don't know why.  Please help. This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAX 100000
int tabA[MAX];
int tabB[MAX];
int tabC[MAX];
int k;

void scope(int size){
int i, max = 0, min;

min = tabA[1];

    for(i = 1; i <= size; i++){
        if(tabA[i] > max)
            max = tabA[i];
        if(tabA[i] < min)
            min = tabA[i];
    }

    k = max - min + 1;
}

void rand1(int size){
    int i;
    srand(time(NULL));

    for(i = 0; i <= size; i++)
        tabA[i] = rand() % 8;
} 

void countingsort(int size){
    int i;

    for(i = 0; i < k; i++)
        tabC[i] = 0;

    for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
        tabC[tabA[i + 1]] = tabC[tabA[i + 1]] + 1;

    for(i = 1; i <= k; i++)
        tabC[i] = tabC[i] + tabC[i - 1];

    for(i = size; i >= 1; i--){
        tabB[tabC[tabA[i]]] = tabA[i];
        tabC[tabA[i]] = tabC[tabA[i]] - 1;
    }   
}

int main(void){
    int size, i;

    printf("Please write how many numbers you wont to sort: ");
    scanf("%d", &size);

    rand1(size);
    scope(size);
    countingsort(size);

    printf("Numbers to sort:\n");
    for(i = 1; i <= size; i++)
        printf("%d\n", tabA[i]);

    printf("\nK: %d\n\n", k);

    printf("Sorting numbers:\n");
    for(i = 1; i <= size; i++)
        printf("%d\n", tabB[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

Thank's for all help.

Comment: why do you accumulate the numbers in `tabC` in the cycle from 1 to k in countingsort. Also  why is your first cycle from 0 to k exclusive and the second from 1 to k? Counting sort is supposed to take 4 lines. I think you are overcomplicating it.

Comment: because i've this code:
http://inf.ug.edu.pl/~gmadejsk/asd/img/countingsort.png

Comment: I have NEVER seen such implementation of counting sort. Still notice that the bottom most cycle is over `j`, while the index variable used for the array elements is `i`... this code seems very strange to me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least this code:

```
for(i = 0; i < k; i++)
    tabC[i] = 0;

for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
    tabC[tabA[i + 1]] = tabC[tabA[i + 1]] + 1;

for(i = 1; i <= k; i++)
    tabC[i] = tabC[i] + tabC[i - 1];
```

Has the problem, that in the first, intialization loop `i` goes `0..k-1`, but in the last loop `i` goes from `1..k`, while assuming `tabC` is initialized. Also, middle loop assumes range of `tabA` values is `0..k`, which it might not be (looking at randomization function, it actually probably is, but this is just co-incidence I suppose).